# Apache Tika Language detection: Asian languages enhancement

Tags: java, apache-tika, language-detection

I found out that Apache Tika often gets confused with Asian languages (e.g. Japanese, Chinese) with some small pieces of English.

Text sample:

> サンフランシスコ生まれのチョコレートショップ、ダンデライオン・チョコレートからほうじ茶ブレンドの「ホットチョコレートミックス」が新登場。 ドリンクとしてだけでなく、アイスクリームやお餅にかけてもOK。ほうじ茶ホットチョコレート 150g（約5杯分） ￥2,160　©Dandelion Chocolate Japan カカオ豆からチョコレートバーになるまでの全工程を一貫して行う「ビーン・トゥー・バー（Bean to Bar）」メーカーの先駆け的存在、ダンデライオン・チョコレート。その人気商品ホットチョコレートミックスは「自宅でホットチョコレートを飲みたい！」という客からの要望を元に開発されたものだ。ほかのチョコレートバー同様、カカオ豆はシングルオリジンにこだわり、ほろ苦さとフルーティーな酸味のバランスがよいドミニカ共和国産を使用。カカオ本来の豊かな風味を味わえる。 このホットチョコレートミックスが新たに出合ったのが、京都・河原町の日本茶専門店「YUGEN」のほうじ茶だ。宇治を中心に各地の生産者を訪れ、厳選された日本茶のみを扱うYUGEN。ほうじ茶も春に収穫された新芽だけで作られる。その茶葉を石臼でじっくりと挽き、パウダー状にしてブレンドすることで、香ばしさだけでなく、旨味、甘み、栄養成分までそのまま溶け込む、深みのある味わいのホットチョコレートが誕生。 オンラインストアでも購入できるので、チョコレートとほうじ茶のおいしいマリアージュを自宅で堪能して。 ダンデライオン・チョコレート ファクトリー&カフェ蔵前 東京都台東区蔵前4-14-6 tel：03-5833-7270 営）10時〜20時（L.O. 19時30分） 不定休 https://dandelionchocolate.jp ※4/12まで休業中。そのほかの店舗詳細情報はウェブサイトで要確認。 ※この記事に記載している価格は、軽減税率8％の税込価格です。 【関連記事】 産地の魅力が際立つ、誘惑の「Bean to Bar」。 マロン×カカオ、ビーン・トゥ・バー発想のモンブラン。

```
languageDetector.detect() -> en: MEDIUM (0.570320)

languageDetector.detectAll() -> ArrayList(size=1) en: MEDIUM (0.570320)
```

I'm using default LanguageDetector implementation: OptimaizeLangDetector

Code sample:

```
        LanguageDetector languageDetector = LanguageDetector.getDefaultLanguageDetector().loadModels();
        languageDetector.addText(text);
        var result = languageDetector.detect().getLanguage();
```

I figured out that after splitting a text into small pieces (n-gramms) Tika searches for the match in `wordLangProbMap`. It's built only from 114k n-gramms for all languages. That leads to the situation when most of the Japanese symbols (n-gramms) are not found in that map, while all english n-gramms are correctly identified. As a result, for either Japanese or Chinese texts Tika often identifies language as a French, German, English and so on.

Is there any way to extend list over which the matching is done?

I'm also considering other alternatives if they could behave in a better way. Previously I used [lingua](https://github.com/pemistahl/lingua), but it really shows dramatic performance drop and resources usage on big texts.

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using?

Comment: @Gagravarr 1.23

Comment: Just as note; performance of Lingua has been improved in the latest releases and there is now also the builder method [`LanguageDetectorBuilder.withLowAccuracyMode()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.github.pemistahl/lingua/1.2.2/com/github/pemistahl/lingua/api/LanguageDetectorBuilder.html#withLowAccuracyMode()).